# Atom Nuclide: Certificate is not yet valid error

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I am trying to connect from Nuclide to an AWS remote server.

Why am I getting this error

```
Certificate is not yet valid
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem on my Nuclide (v 0.178.0), which was installed via apm from the command line.

Since, according to the [official Nuclide website](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/), "installing Nuclide within the Atom Packages UI is the recommended method," I uninstalled my Nuclide and reinstalled it via the UI. This magically solved the problem.

Hope it helps.